# d3: HTTP404 NOT FOUND error

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have just started learning d3 and am trying to point localhost at the html file I created. It shows a blank page and HTTP404 NOT FOUND error, despite me adding some text to the source code. 
[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofZ6W.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoCT8.png)

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Does your d3.v3.js in the location of

http://localhost/project-folder/D3/project-file/d3/d3.v3.js ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a subdirectory mismatched between your html referencing the d3 Javascript file and the actual location. One simple solution is to replace it with CDN - i.e., get it from a publicly available location instead of your own server. To do that, replace:

```
src="d3/d3.v3.js"
```

with:

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"
```

for the latest version 4.9.1.